# Trouble using an Oracle View in Models.py

Tags: python, django, oracle

My group and I are attempting to rewrite our website. We are keeping an Oracle database back-end, and rewriting the front-end with Python Django.

No problem connecting to Oracle, or accessing the datatables. Now I'm trying to add an Oracle view to the models.py, and I can't get it to work.

I googled this question with many results, so I know it is possible and apparently common, but I can't get it to work.

All I've done so far is add the class to models.py. We are using PhCharm as our IDE.

When I try to access the data using the Python Console, I can import the class, but when I try to load the QuerySet I get the error "Unable to get repr for " in the result window.

Does anyone see something I'm missing from my model?

Here is the model:

```
class LawBillRoleActionInfoView(LawBaseClass):
    combo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rltp_role_cd = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    bill_dft_no = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    session_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ebrl_appl_seq = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    enty_id_seq = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lst_nm = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    fst_nm = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    mi = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=145, blank=True, null=True)
    prtydist = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    blac_appl_seq = models.IntegerField(blank=None, null=True)
    role_descr = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    shr_ttl = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    lmt_ind = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    bltp_bill_typ_cd = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    bill_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    actn_descr = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    actn_dt = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sess_law_chpt_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'law_bill_role_action_info_vw'
    unique_together = (('bill_dft_no', 'rltp_role_cd', 'session_id'),)
    app_label = 'laws'
```

Here are the commands I am running from the Python Console:

```
from laws.models import LawBillRoleActionInfoView
bill_qs = LawBillRoleActionInfoView.objects.all()
```

Here is the LawBaseClass:

## Base Class

```
class LawBaseClass(models.Model):
    """
    Base class
    """
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    dtm_created = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    mod_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    dtm_mod = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    abstract = True
```

Comment: How did you do this? Did you use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)?

Comment: Paulo, thanks for answering. No I did not use inspectdb. I will however, look into it and give it a try. I'm not familiar yet with the IDE, or Python and Django in general. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `managed` should certainly be False, not True. But what is LawBaseClass?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have changed 'managed' to False. The LawBaseClass is another class in models (edited post to include). I tried changing the parameter in LawBillRoleActionInfoView to models.Model but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you write `__str__(self)` or `unicode` model method? ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624232/842935 )

Comment: @danihp - neither. What I posted is what I have so far, regarding the view.